# Android Volley NoConnectionError: java.io.InterruptedIOException

Tags: java, android, rest, android-volley, okhttp

I have below code to make request to web service using volley:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity(),new OkHttpStack());
GsonRequest<myData> request = new GsonRequest<myData>(Method.POST,Config.MYPOSTLINK, myData.class, getSuccessListener, getErrorListener);
request.setParams("Token", token);        
requestQueue.add(request);
```

I have implemented OkHttpStack.java as [like this](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/5616899):

```
public class OkHttpStack extends HurlStack {
    private final OkHttpClient client;

    public OkHttpStack() {
        this(new OkHttpClient());
    }

    public OkHttpStack(OkHttpClient client) {
        if (client == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Client must not be null.");
        }
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        return new OkUrlFactory(client).open(url);
    }
}
```

Sometimes i get error below:

```
00.482    com.ex W/System.err﹕ com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
00.483    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
00.483    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
00.483    com.ex W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
00.483    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
00.483    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:73)
00.483    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
00.483    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:221)
00.483    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.flush(HttpConnection.java:141)
00.483    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.finishRequest(HttpTransport.java:52)
00.483    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:902)
00.483    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:788)
00.484    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)
00.484    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
00.484    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
00.484    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
00.484    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
00.484    com.ex W/System.err﹕ ... 1 more
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:73)
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:221)
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.flush(HttpConnection.java:141)
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.finishRequest(HttpTransport.java:52)
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:902)
00.589    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:788)
00.590    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)
00.590    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
00.590    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
00.590    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
00.590    com.ex W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
00.590    com.ex W/System.err﹕ ... 1 more
```

How to overcome ? Any way to rerequest if i get this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was doing another request before this one and actually that was giving error. I implemented above `requestQueue` code into that one as well and no error now. Code above (mine) works cool.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code as follow:

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory;

public class OkHttpStack extends HurlStack {
    private final OkUrlFactory mFactory;

    public OkHttpStack() {
        this(new OkHttpClient());
    }

    public OkHttpStack(OkHttpClient client) {
        if (client == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Client must not be null.");
        }
        mFactory = new OkUrlFactory(client);
    }
}
```

You can reference my [code](https://github.com/CloudedDragon/eocboxVolleyBox/blob/master/eocboxVolleyBox/src/main/java/app/eocbox/com/volley/toolbox/OkHttpStack.java) to implement **OkHttpStack**

***Update:**

> Maybe you can check when you customize the requestQueue code. Did you add **requestQueue.start()** in your code? If you did it,and then it will show the **interruptedioexception** certainly.